# Devise error「undefined method `errors' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd10be58b00>」

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

If you press the users / edit link, you will get an error like the one below.

> NoMethodError in Users::Registrations#edit

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'user/show'

  devise_for :users, controllers: { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "users/registrations" }

  root 'home#index'
  get 'home/show'

  #User MyPage
  resources :users
```

Why does this error occur?

We prepared an application that causes errors in github. After logging in after signing up, pressing the My page will result in the corresponding error.

[github‌​.com/tib777/sample](http://github%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B.com/tib777/sample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave a look at your project, installed it and run in my local machine.

the cause of the problem is that when you do the `get` request for `users/edit` that mapped to your `app/controllers/users/registrations#edit` action that runs the ['devise controller edit action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)', this action renders a form that uses the `resource` helper method to display that data from your current user.

This is done inside the `devise registrations` controller, with the following method before running the edit action

```
  # Authenticates the current scope and gets the current resource from the session.
  def authenticate_scope!
    send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", force: true)
    self.resource = send(:"current_#{resource_name}")
  end
```

`resource_name` will be `user` in your case, but could be `admin` depending on how you installed devise. So it will return that `user` saved in the `resource` variable

In your case this is failing

When you render your form

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
```

as you can check from the console of the error message `resource` will return a NameError..

this is all what I know for now, I may add more later.. I don't have the solution, but you should try to debug the controller from your gem files to understand why devise is not instantiating the user variable when performing this get request. Somehow it loses the user.